# Sort command for a .txt file not operating in a VBA Shell

Tags: excel, vba

I believe I've replicated the stachoverflow recommended code to sort a .txt file using VBA in Excel. The following is the relevant code from my program.  It processes this code without error but does not produce the sorted output file. The IntualityInputRealTimeFIFOTable file is produced correctly.  Can't figure out what I'm doing wrong.

```
Public MyCommand As String
.
.
IntualityInputRealTimeFIFOTable = WorkbookPath & "IntualityInputRealTimeFIFOTable.txt"
IntualityInputRealTimeFIFOTableTemp = WorkbookPath & "IntualityInputRealTimeFIFOTableTemp.txt"
.
.
Close #3
MyCommand = "Sort IntualityInputRealTimeFIFOTable /O IntualityInputRealTimeFIFOTableTemp"
Shell MyCommand, vbHide
```

Comment: You can't embed variables inside quotes in VBA. You concatenate them to the string using `&`, as in `"Sort " & IntualityInputRealTimeFIFOTable & " /D " & IntualityInputRealTimeFIFOTableTemp`.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I have tried that solution and it still does not sort the text file. I'm thinking that it might be the comma-delimited text records that is causing the problem.   Here's a sample of IntualityInputRealTimeFIFOTable

Comment: 11/13/2019,26,26,26,2020 Democratic Presidential Nomination = Warren
11/7/2019,1,1,1,2020 Democratic Presidential Nomination = Williamson
11/13/2019,4,4,4,2020 Democratic Presidential Nomination = Yang
11/13/2019,49,45,45,2020 Generic Congressional Vote = Democrats
11/13/2019,40,37,37,2020 Generic Congressional Vote = Republicans
10/16/2019,2,2,2,2020 Republican Presidential Nomination = Sanford

Comment: the date/time stamp is the beginning of each record

Comment: It's sorting properly. `11/13/2019` comes before `11/7/2019`, because `11/1` sorts alphabetically before `11/7`. Don't expect Sort to interpret the data to understand that they're dates - it does a strictly alphabetical sort.

Comment: Got it. I'll give it a try.